# In the Mueller report, what are the SM-[number]-[word] documents in the footnotes?

Tags: united-states, reference-request, mueller-investigation, classified-information

Some parts of the [Mueller report](https://games-cdn.washingtonpost.com/notes/prod/default/documents/f5fe536c-81bb-45be-86e5-a9fee9794664/note/a8d336ef-e98d-4a08-987d-b4c154b22700.pdf) regarding the investigation into alleged Russian interference with the 2016 US presidential elections, some of the footnotes refer to documents with coded names/titles. Examples:

> 113. See SM-2589105 serials 144 & 495.
> 114. See SM-2589105-HACK, serial 5.
> 115. See SM-2589105-GJ, serial 649.

What do these footnotes refer to, and are these publicly-available documents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On page 14 of the report, a footnote (partly redacted) says:

> SM-2230634, serial 44 (analysis). The FBI case number cited here, and
> other FBI case numbers identified in the report, should be treated as
> law enforcement sensitive given the context.

This suggests that the SM-####### notation is an **FBI case file number**, included as reference for those who have access to such things. I'm not familiar with the FBI's case file notation, but from what I see on the web these numbers aren't arbitrary, but include codes for particular criminal acts, investigating offices, and other sundry information.

Comment: And just to be extra-explicit - the contents of these case files has not been made public, right?

Comment: @einpoklum: So far as I know. Generally speaking, FBI case files would *not* be made public without an explicit court order, but I don't happen to know whether the juridical order that unsealed this document included supplementary material. If it did, that material is not included with the on-line versions of the text that I have seen.